# Gulp + Babel + Webpack + Karma: Use sourcemaps for stacktrace

Tags: angularjs, gulp, webpack, karma-runner, babeljs

In an AngularJS 1 project we use Gulp to compile the project with webpack and test it with Karma. We cannot get sourcemaps to work as expected.

I found the obvious plug-in (https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-sourcemap-loader) but this seems to exist only to use sourcemaps while debugging karma tests, NOT to display a usable stacktrace.

I also found https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-source-map-support which seems to be exclusive for browserify.

Am I missing something here? Has anyone gotten this to work?

**Appended info:**

This is the unusable output (note index.module.js, the webpack compiled file, which has inline sourcemaps):

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 629 of 629 (1 FAILED) (6.663 secs / 6.531 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 628 SUCCESS

1) should A B not be A B
   TrajectDetails Controller _aMethod()
   Expected Object({ a: Object({ x: [ 'A', 'B' ] }) }) not to be Object({ materieel: Object({ x: [ 'A', 'B' ] }) }).
   .tmp/serve/app/index.module.js:93820:42

[11:02:26] 'test' errored after 9.37 s
[11:02:26] Error: Failed 1 tests.
```

This is how my karma config looks:

```
var preprocessors = {};
pathSrcJs.forEach(function (path) {
    preprocessors[path] = ['babel', 'sourcemap'];
});
pathSrcHtml.forEach(function (path) {
    preprocessors[path] = ['ng-html2js'];
});

var configuration = {
    files: listFiles(),
    preprocessors: preprocessors,
    singleRun: true,
    colors: true,
    autoWatch: false,
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        stripPrefix: conf.paths.src + '/',
        moduleName: 'xx-xx'
    },
    logLevel: 'INFO',
    frameworks: ['source-map-support', 'jasmine'],
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    plugins: [
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-coverage',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
        'karma-spec-reporter',
        'karma-babel-preprocessor',
        'karma-sourcemap-loader',
        'karma-source-map-support'
    ],
    reporters: ['progress', 'spec'],
};

config.set(configuration);
```

Webpack config is like this:

```
var webpackOptions = {

    watch:  watch,
    module: {
    loaders: [{test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel-loader']}]
        },
    output: {filename: output},
    devtool = 'inline-source-map'
};

var sources = [path.join(conf.paths.src, source)];
sources.push(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.spec.js'));

return gulp.src(sources)
        .pipe(webpack(webpackOptions))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app')));
```